# Rspec.configure: save and restore capybara driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have the following code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # ...

  config.before(:each, billy: true) do
    Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist_billy
  end

  config.after(:each, billy: true) do
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end
```

So every spec tagged with `:billy` is executed with `:poltergeist_billy` capybara driver.

But I have plenty of drivers in my application. I want to restore previously used driver, not just to fall back to default when I execute billy-test.

What's the best way to restore the driver and where should I keep this variable?

Comment: If your tests are run synchronously couldn't you make a global variable pointing to the driver when you change it

Comment: @maxpleaner do you think it's a good idea to create local variable just above the first block and access it from two blocks?

Comment: Sure. Good luck